# Error when using function to return array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to use a function to return a 1D array for my subroutine and am running into error's. Below is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
Sub test()
Dim testArry(1 To 3) As Double

testArry = arryFunction(1.2) 'I get a compile error here "cant assign to array"
End Sub

Function arryFunction(cs As Double) As Double()
Dim anotherArry(1 To 3) As Double

anotherArry(1) = cs
anotherArry(2) = cs + 1
anotherArry(3) = cs + 3

arryFunction = anotherArry
End Function
```

I have tried searching for this online and can not find a solution, at least one that I understand therefore, would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I havent yet found documentation to support this it looks like you error is due to you cannot assign an array to another of fixed size. Possibly since the array needs to be `ReDim`'ed during the copy but that is just speculation. This does work however

```
Sub test()
    Dim testArry() As Double
    testArry = arryFunction(1.2) 'I get a compile error here "cant assign to array"
End Sub
```